# JNI - sending class instances to C++

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I want to send a struct-like object from Java to C++. Since there are no structs in java I guess I have to write a class and then send an instance of that class.

```
public class soundSource {
     int posX;
     int posY;
     .....
}
```

But... the jObject I get from JNI method in C++ - how do I extract individual fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dennis's answer is correct, however, there's another way you can do this, which might give you better performance, and that is via direct byte-buffers.

Here are the docs you need to read:
[JNI NIO support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#nio_support), 
[ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

You allocate the direct byte-buffer either on the Java side or the C side. You then populate the buffer, on the java side, using ByteBuffer's methods, according to your c-struct's layout.
Just remember that these buffers must be deallocated when you're done using them, but you can reuse the same buffer to pass data back-and-forth.

Comment: how do you access the member of the buffer? If you take for granted that the native side knows that buffer contains a double, followed by an int, followed by a char, how would the values be accessed? So on the Java side you do `putDouble(1.2); putInt(4); putChar('p');`, how do you get them in the native code? Just interested as I've never tried this approach before.

Comment: @Dennis - you simply cast the buffer pointer (on the C side) to the corresponding struct type, with the appropriate member definitions.

Comment: so `struct TEST{double a; int b; char c;} out = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,theBuffer);` ?? Nice.

Comment: @Dennis almost: `struct TEST{double a; int b; char c;} *out = (TEST*)(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,theBuffer);`

Comment: @jxgn You'll need to call String.getBytes() with some charset that your native code understands, say UTF-8, and then put that array into the buffer. You might need to copy the array into another one and add a 0 at the end, if your native code expects a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

```
jstr = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, obj, fid);
```

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html.

You are not "sending" the data anywhere though. You are just using the JNI interface to the JVM to access data.
You don't actually even need the field to be public. Just do that for all the fields of the class you are interested in and you can populate your struct in C++.